# Reading XML file and displaying it to HTML

Tags: html, xml, powershell

Question: How do i get the data from the xml to output to the html like seem in the image

I'm trying to get the data from an xml file to be displayed on a html webpage. Ever time I try it doesn't format it how I'm wanting it to. I don't know if I'm missing something.

The XML is formatted like this.

```
<service>
  <jobFilter>
    <name>Name of the overall job</name>
    <job>jobname</job>
    <status>suspended</status>
    <job>jobname</job>
    <status>ready</status>
    <job>jobname</job>
    <status>ready</status>
  </jobFilter>
</service>
```

This is the code that I'm using to try and get it to display

```
function CompareStatus {

# read in the XML data from the monitoringXXX.xml file
[XML] $BeforeFile = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\cnelson011\CompareFileBefore.xml 

$css = Get-Content C:\Users\cnelson011\monitoringcss.css
$htmlOut = '<html>
  <head><style>' + $css + '</style>
     <title>ESB Service Monitoring </title>
   </head>
  <body>'

foreach ($serv in $BeforeFile.sList.service.jobFilter) {
    $serv.name

  $htmlOut = $htmlOut + '
<div><hr></div></br>
<div id="' + $serv.name + '" style="text-align:center; font-size:18pt"><strong>' + $serv.name + '</strong></div>
</br>' }

if ($serv.jobFilter) {
$htmlOut = $htmlOut + '
<table class="minimalistBlack">
    <caption><strong>Comparistion</strong></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Job</th
            <th scope="col">Status Before</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
'}
$BeforeFile1 = $BeforeFile.sList.service.jobFilter
foreach ($sName in $BeforeFile1) {
 
    $JobName = $sName.job
    $Status = $sName.status
    
    
 
    if ($BeforeFile1.name -contains $JobName) {
    
    $htmlOut = $htmlOut + "<tr>
       <td><strong>"+ $JobName +"</strong></td>
       <td>" + $Status + "</td>"}
    $htmlOut = $htmlOut + "</tr>"
    
}

$htmlOut = $htmlOut + '  </tbody>
</table></br>
'

$htmlName = "compare.html"
# create the HTML page and display it
$htmlOut | Out-File -FilePath $htmlName
ii $htmlName    
    
}
```

The css code

```
.greenBox {
background-color:green;
}
.redBox {
background-color:red;
}
.amberBox {
background-color:yellow;
}

table.minimalistBlack {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.minimalistBlack td, table.minimalistBlack th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 4px;
}
table.minimalistBlack tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.minimalistBlack thead {
  background: #CFCFCF;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}
table.minimalistBlack thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
}
table.minimalistBlack tfoot {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
}
table.minimalistBlack tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

The image is the format that I'm trying to get this xml to look like.
[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @shadow2020 How do i get the data from the xml to output to the html like seem in the image